# Assignment between pointers work only inside main, not in procedure body

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm getting a ***segmentation fault*** error, if I try to make a copy between pointers to a struct, inside a procedure body.

If I instead, make the copy between pointers within the `main()` body, everything works correctly.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
  int value;
  struct node *father, *lchild, *rchild;
} node;

typedef struct node Node;

// Prototypes
Node* insertRoot(int val, Node* N);


int main(){

  Node * A = NULL;

  Node * b = insertRoot(10, A);

  //A = b;  // If I do the assignment here it works correctly.

  printf("A->value = %d \n\n" , A->value);  //Segmentation fault!

  return 0;
}

Node* insertRoot(int val, Node* N){
  Node* temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  temp->value = val;
  temp->father = NULL;
  temp->lchild = NULL;
  temp->rchild = NULL;

  N = temp; // If I do the assignment here instead, it won't work.

  return temp;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning any value to `A` inside `insertRoot`, you are assigning to `N` which is a copy of `A`. That leaves the value `A=NULL` unchanged.

Comment: So, do I have to pass a pointer to A in `insertRoot` signature, instead of just A if I want to copy the value in `A`, and not in a copy of `A`?

Comment: You can do that, but why don't you just get rid of the second `inserRoot` parameter and do `A = insertRoot(10)`?

Comment: That was just a minimal sample code I wrote to show more clearly what was the problem. In my full code `inserRoot` is a void function, so I have to make the copy between pointers inside its body.

Comment: Then yes, if you need to modify `A`, which is a `Node*`, you can pass a pointer to `A` which would be a `Node**`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue. I haven't used C in a while and I wrongly assumed pointers were passed by reference.